# Can multiple tasks be run simultaneously on a netbook?

Tags: cpu, netbook, laptop

What are the major disadvantages of a netbook in comparison with a common laptop?

Comment: Your title does not fit the question.

Comment: Regarding your title, the answer is the same [as for your other question](http://superuser.com/questions/222177/can-only-one-application-be-run-on-a-tablet-pc-at-a-single-time). Regarding the text, it's mostly screen size, performance, and perhaps battery life -- everything that suffers from the small size (and price).

Answer (score 2):

To answer the title, yes, but just be careful how many and what you run. Call of Duty 7 is not going to run alone. Office, pidgin, and Firefox will run fine on any netbook. (admittedly chrome runs better)

Your OS will also depend on how well things run. XP seems to run very nicely, Linux can be bloated, or very slim and fast. I can't speak for windows 7, but I've heard lousy things about Starter Edition.

The big disadvantage is the speed. Ram can be upgraded, allowing for better multitasking. 
Also, the lack of a CD drive can be a disadvantage. 
The screens are small and sometimes hard to see, and some programs do not scale well to them. Inkscape is a prime example.
The keyboards take some getting use to, be in general are pretty good, YMMV. 
I've found a lot of the tracpads suck quite badly, sketchy multitouch, rough on the skin surfaces, lousy sensitivity even with configurations. 
Also, most netbooks, are very hard to upgrade or fix, anything beyond the ram. Your better off ordering anything extra you need at the OEM level usually.

I have a Asus 1000HE.

My mom had and broke a ASUS 1005HAB.

I've taken both apart, the 1000he is a great machine in every way, the 1005 is not. 
We just got a 12" asus netbook. I am unsure of the model number.